# AWS IVS Playback key across multiple private channels?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cloud, streaming

Hello I see there's a limit of 3 playback key pairs. Can I use a keypair across multiple private channels? My use case is a ugc streaming app where all channels are paid for and require authorization to view.

Workflow for a private channel  is as follows:

1)When a viewer tries to load the webpage for a private stream, the browser requests an access token. (The customer provides the browser code to do this.)

2)The customer’s backend app receives the access-token request and determines whether that viewer should be authorized to view the stream. If yes, the backend generates a JWT, uses the customer’s private key to sign it, and returns the signed JWT in a playback request to the browser.

3)The browser loads the stream, using a request to the Amazon IVS player (or other player) SDK. The request contains the stream playback URL and the signed JWT.

4)Amazon IVS uses the customer’s public key to verify that the JWT was signed using the correct private key.

5)If the JWT is verified, Amazon IVS plays the private stream for the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use a playback key across multiple channels.